# wp_nav_menu Returning nothing

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

So I have come to move my HTML site over to wordpress and im having issues with the menu. None of the links listed in the admin panel pull through.

header.php code:

```
<nav>
<?php
wp_nav_menu(array(
  'theme_location' => 'top-menu',
  'items_wrap'=> '<ul class="nav__links"><li>',
  'container' => '',
));
?>
</nav>
```

This is the nav bar html:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="nav__links">
    <li><a class="un" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="un" href="#">Services <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Broadband</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Broadband</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Broadband</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Broadband</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Broadband</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Broadband</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Broadband</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Broadband</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Broadband</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="un" href="#">Customers</a></li>
    <li><a class="un" href="#">News & Blog</a></li>
    <li><a class="un" href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a class="un" href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The code in my functions.php file:

```
function wp_custom_new_menu() {
register_nav_menus(
  array(
    'top-menu' => __( 'Top Menu' ),
    'mobile' => __( 'Mobile Menu' )
  )
);}add_action( 'init', 'wp_custom_new_menu' );
```

This is what is being pulled through:

```
<nav>
<ul class="nav__links"><li>    </li></ul></nav>
```

Im not entirely sure why its doing this, There is definitly a menu created within the wordpress admin area. Display location top menu has been checked also.

Any pointers would be great.

Thanks,
HizY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items_wrap'`usually defines the elements that wrap the `li` elements of the menu, so having an `<li>` tag here (like in your code) would cause `li` elements as direct children of that `li`, which is not valid HTML (i.e. submenus would require `ul` children of `li` in between). That most likely is the cause for nothing showing up.

So you'd have to delete that `<li>`, and also add a closing `</ul>`. But actually it should be sufficient to use `'menu_class' => 'nav__links'` *instead* of that. The wrapping of the menu items inside `ul` and `li` tags happens automatically, and `menu_class` adds a class to the `ul`.

So the resulting php code would be

```
<?php
 wp_nav_menu(array(
  'theme_location' => 'top-menu',
  'menu_class' => 'nav__links',
  'container' => '',
 ));
?>
```